# Simple Online Checker

Tags: php, session-variables

Working on making it easy to tell if a user is online or offline with the CMS I'm building and as of right now I have

```
class IUser {
    public function User($arg) {
        switch($arg) {
            case "online":
            self::CheckKey();
            break;
        }
    }
    public function CheckKey() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['key']['userid'])) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then for the actual check I have

```
$user = new IUser();
if($user->User("online") == true) {
    echo "user online";
}
else {
    echo "user offline";
}
```

So in theory it should show user offline when the id key hasn't been set, but instead it just always returns false. If anyone sees what I'm doing wrong here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the idea behind this... The user is mean to check in his own session if he is online? How can he be offline for that?

Comment: No. this is for plugin creation etc. Rather than having the author write `if(isset($_SESSION['key']['userid']) { //do stuff }` It's just a general way to where after I create the hook they can use `if(User("online")== true { //do stuff }`

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. Sure, you can use that notation in your conditional. But the question remains: why should a user check his own online status inside a web application? Because I don't see why some other users id should be found in `$_SESSION`. But maybe I miss something here or do you creative things with your session container.

Comment: The user themself isn't checking their status. Say I write a plugin to include that is a login panel. 
`if(User("online") == true { LoadPanel("online"); }
else { LoadPanel("offline"); } `
I'm not sure how else to describe what I'm working on here. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `User` function doesn't return anything. You need an extra `return` to propagate the result of the check to the caller:

```
public function User($arg) {
    switch($arg) {
        case "online":
        return self::CheckKey();  // < -- At the start of this line.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought by defining to return within the CheckKey function I was doing what I needed to to get the value through, but adding that simple return worked like a charm. Thanks again. No telling how long I would have been banging my head over that little bit of text.

Comment: The return value in CheckKey is nicely returned to User, but there it was ignored instead of being returned again to calling code snippet. Returns don't 'bubble up', in contrast to, for example, exceptions. But I guess you'll never forget that from now on. :)

Comment: That is correct. I know from this point on. Working on my own web application and this just seemed cleaner than drafting plugins with the isset session, just a simple is the user online true, so it's probably the most complex I've gotten, but pushing myself outside of my comfort zone has made me learn a lot more than I thought I would ever know :)

Answer (score 0):

Your User() function must return something...

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['key']['userid'] = 1;


class IUser
{
    public function User( $arg )
    {
        switch( $arg ) {
            case "online":
                return self::CheckKey();
            break;
        }
    }
    public function CheckKey()
    {
        if( isset( $_SESSION['key']['userid'] ) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$user = new IUser();
if( $user->User( "online" )  ) {

    echo "user online";

} else {

    echo "user offline";

}

?>
```

Comment: Wish it was that simple I actually have the session variable set manually in my pre loader file `session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = array(
 'userid' => sha1(1),
 'username' => sha1("orion5814"),
 'email'  => sha1("green.morgan87@gmail.com"),
 ); `

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as you use return in your User() function. This is just an usage example. Now, if you are checking another user and not your status, that's another story...